# Is the cone as solid a topological manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

When one says that the cone in $R^3$ is a topological manifold, is it meant the cone as a surface or as a solid? Whereas I can understand it is a 2-manifold as a surface, I don't understand it is a manifold as solid.

Can somebody clarify this?  Many thanks.

Comment: You get the same thing with the sphere, right? Either it's a surface or it's a solid. Do you have any trouble in that case?

Comment: @Arthur. Can the identity map work as homomorhism between the cone-solid and $R^3$? In that case, the cone-solid as a subset of $R^3$ would be a 3-manifold, right?